# React : TypeError: Cannot read property 'Item' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I want to access the value of state/property in new state prop. Actually I have already state property where I am storing value of Item=5 and I create UrlParam Where I am storing URL but I need Item numeric value in URL property. I am new to React , Somebody please help me how to do this ?

When I getting Error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'Item' of undefined` , Could someone please help me ?

**Code**

```
 this.state={
  Item : 5,
  skip:0,
  urlParams:`http://localhost:8001/meetups?filter[limit]=${(this.state.Item)}&&filter[skip]=${this.state.skip}`
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As another answer mentioned, it looks like you are trying to use `this.state.Item` before the assignment expression `this.state={...}` is complete.

That said, it looks a bit like you want `urlParams` to always stay up-to-date with the new values of `Item` and `skip`.  If that's the case, you may want to implement it as a helper function instead of a property of `state`.

```js
class Example extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    
    this.state = {
      Item: 5,
      skip: 0
    }
    
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  urlParams() {
    return `http://localhost:8001/parties?filter[limit]=${(this.state.Item)}&&filter[skip]=${this.state.skip}`
  }
  
  handleClick() {
    this.setState({skip: this.state.skip + 1})
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <a href={this.urlParams()}>Example link</a>
        <pre>{this.urlParams()}</pre>
        <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Change link</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

    
ReactDOM.render(<Example/>, document.querySelector('div#my-example' ))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="my-example"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks it working!! but I need more .. Actually I want to implement logic for example if user click on button I want to update that function `urlParams()` I mean to say that I want to update the URL

Comment: For that you'll want to call `setState()` in a click event handler.  I've added this to my example and made it a runnable snippet so you can try it out.  For more about how `setState()` works, I recommend reading https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html.

Answer (score 2):

When the value for `urlParams` is interpolated `this.state` is not defined yet.

Either define `Item` and `skip` as a separate variables or set `this.state.urlParams` afterwards:

```
const Item = 5;
const skip = 0;
 this.state={
  Item,
  skip,
  urlParams:`http://localhost:8001/parties?filter[limit]=${(Item)}&&filter[skip]=${skip}`
}
```

or

```
 this.state={
  Item : 5,
  skip:0
};
  this.state.urlParams = `http://localhost:8001/parties?filter[limit]=${(this.state.Item)}&&filter[skip]=${this.state.skip}`;
```

Comment: Actually , I want this inside in state because later on I am updating it state .